# In-app purchase for Mac OS X application

Tags: objective-c, macos, in-app-purchase

I need to code in-app purchasing in my Mac OS X app. I haven't found any information about this. Does the in-app-purchase technology work in OS X applications or does it exist for iOS only?

Answer (score 3):

From the iTunesConnect Developer Guide:

> In-App Purchase functionality requires
>   iOS 3.0 or higher for iOS apps and Mac
>   OS 10.7 or higher for Mac OS apps.
>
> For complete guidelines and
>   instructions on In-App Purchase, see
>   the App Store Quick Reference: Getting
>   Started with In-App Purchase on iOS
>   and the [In-App Purchase Programming
>   Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: I not be able to code in-app-purchase from 10.6.7 (ex. compile proj)?

Comment: @lagssss: Are you asking if the documentation is incorrect? My guess is no, though I could be wrong.